# Loop through JSON to put result in HTML

Tags: html, arrays, json

I'm just starting with JSON and JavaScript and I am having some difficulties parsing JSON result. This is because there is a variable array with within episodes array the JSON that I want to have. So this is an array in an array if I'm right.

Example code:

```
{
   "description":"This is a description",
   "banner":"This is a banner",
   "episodes":{
      "15":[
         {
            "id":"28685",
            "active":1,
            "lang":"en",
            "link":"http:\/\/link.com\video.php?hd=1"
         }
      ],
      "14":[
         {
            "id":"28577",
            "active":1,
            "lang":"ru",
            "link":"http:\/\/link.com\video.php?hd=1"
         }
]};
```

The "15 and 14" are episode numbers, and id, active, lang, and links are properties from that episode.

So in HTML I want to display that as a group together. Can anyone help me out on this, because I can't find any results on the JQuery page how to get those variable episode number array name.

Maybe to make it a bit more clear. This is my JSON source, and i want to create a video page from it. Where it lists all these episodes with the properties. I'm planning on putting this together with the twitter bootstrap library. The description is the "description from the tv serie" banner is for the banner image, and the list above here are episode 15 and 14. I want to be able to click on such an episodelink. The only think i have difficulties with getting it all apart in different objects: Full json: http://pastie.org/6635498

And it needs to be dynamic this way if the Json updates it also updates the html, that way i can't make static references to "15"

Some quick html i've made to be the target idea: http://pastie.org/6635571

Comment: can you share the html sample how you want it

Comment: where is the variable `"node" ` in given JSON

Comment: What do you mean by "as a group together?"  What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe to make it a bit more clear. This is my JSON source, and i want to create a video page from it. Where it lists all these episodes with the properties. I'm planning on putting this together with the twitter bootstrap library. The description is the "description from the tv serie" banner is for the banner image, and the list above here are episode 15 and 14. I want to be able to click on such an episodelink. The only think i have difficulties with getting it all apart in different objects: Full json: http://pastie.org/6635498. Exampe output: put the json in here: http://json.bloople.net

Answer (score 1):

using jquery you can convert your json string (assuming it's a valid json string) to a javascript object like this:

```
var jsonObj =  $.parseJSON('{
   "description":"This is a description",
   "banner":"This is a banner",
   "episodes":{
      "15":[
         {
            "id":"28685",
            "active":1,
            "lang":"en",
            "link":"http:\/\/link.com\video.php?hd=1"
         }
      ],
      "14":[
         {
            "id":"28577",
            "active":1,
            "lang":"ru",
            "link":"http:\/\/link.com\video.php?hd=1"
         }
]}');
```

from here you can access the json data in javascript like this (e.g. for episode 15's id):

```
var episode15id = jsonObj['episodes']['15']['id'];
```

then thru javascript magic you can put that into your html:

html:

```
<div id="jsondatahere" ></div>
```

js:

```
$("#jsondatahere").html(episode15id);
```

Comment: I think OP already has a JSON object - you can skip the `$.parseJSON()` part